# how to take the information of a div into a popup box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i display in every lign informations that are in the database, what i want is when i click on one of the buttons the informations of the div to show in the popup box, now it only show me the one of the last div i hope you can help me. here is my code:

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1)), url(img/695586.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;

}

/*#contenaire{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:15%;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
}*/

.cont{
 position:relative;
 width:95%;
 height:450px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top:4%;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius:20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(88, 83, 74, .7);
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.med{
     position:relative;
     width:96%;
     height:7%;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top:10px;
     /*background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
     background-color: azure;
     border-radius:20px;
     padding: 5px 16px 5px 20px;
}

.Column
{
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.btn{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.btn:hover{
    color:cadetblue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid Black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
/*::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 12px;  
  height: 12px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
.liens{
     float:left;
     width:100px;
     height: 100px;
     /*background-color:antiquewhite;*/
     position:relative;
     width:20%;
     height:auto;
     margin-left: 2%;
     margin-right: 2%;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     border-radius:20px;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(88, 83, 74, .7);
     padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}
.liens{
    list-style: none;
}

.liens li a{
    /*color: #000;*/
    color: #d9dcdb;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.liens li a:hover{
    color:cadetblue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid cadetblue;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.formulaire{
     float:left;
     height: auto;
     width: 70%;
     background-color:snow;
     position:relative;
     border-radius:20px;
     padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
     color: black;
}

.titre{
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}
.modal_close
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.close
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.modal_main
{
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:16%;
    border-radius:4px;
    left:24%;
    display:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
.modaltwo
{
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:16%;
    border-radius:4px;
    left:24%;
    display:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}

.modalthree{
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:16%;
    border-radius:4px;
    left:24%;
    display:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(20px)}100%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}}
```

html

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    // Check to see if actually logged in. If not, redirect to login page
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/formulaire.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>LifeCare</title>
        <style type="text/css">
      .med:hover input[type="submit"]
      {
            visibility:visible !important; 
      }
        </style>  
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function popup(){
                $(".modal").fadeIn();
                $(".modal_main").show();
                $(".close").click(function(){
                    $(".modal").fadeOut();
                    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
                });

            }  
            function popup2() {
                $(".modal").fadeIn();
                $(".modaltwo").show();
                $(".close").click(function(){
                    $(".modal").fadeOut();
                    $(".modaltwo").fadeOut();
                });
            }
            function popup3() {
                $(".modal").fadeIn();
                $(".modalthree").show();
                $(".close").click(function(){
                    $(".modal").fadeOut();
                    $(".modalthree").fadeOut();
                });
            }
        </script>
</head>



<?php 
    require 'header.php';
    $id_g = $_SESSION['id_g']; 
    $id_p = $_SESSION['id_p'];
?>

<body>
    <?php
        $req = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nom, Prenom, Type, Adresse from medecin");
        $req->execute();
        $donnees = $req->fetchAll();
    ?>
    <div class="cont">    
        <?php
            foreach($donnees as $donnees){
        ?>
        <div class="med">
            <div class="Column"><?php echo $donnees['Nom']; ?></div>
            <div class="Column" ><?php echo $donnees['Prenom']; ?></div>
            <div class="Column"><?php echo $donnees['Type']; ?></div>
            <div class="Column"><?php echo $donnees['Adresse']; ?></div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Annuler rendez-vous" style="float: right;" onclick="popup(); return false;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Modifier rendez-vous" style="float: right;" onclick="popup2(); return false;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Prendre rendez-vous" style="float: right;" onclick="popup3(); return false;">
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal_close close"></div>
                <div class="modal_main">
                    <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
                    <input type="submit"  style="margin-top:32px;">
                </div>
                <div class="modaltwo">
                    <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
                    <input type="submit" value="salut" style="margin-top:32px;">
                </div>
                <div class="modalthree">
                    <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
                    <p> le medecin <?php echo $donnees['Nom']; ?> </p>
                    <label style="margin-top:32px;">Date du rendez-vous</label>
                    <input type="date" style="margin-top:32px;">
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>




</body>
```

Comment: you need to identify the div/modal with a ID that **needs to be unique**, then, use jQuery to launch and grab the ID. Either you create *one* modal, then pass ID param on click, or keep it your way, but need unique ID as well

Comment: i thought about this one but i didn't know how to give it and id, can u help me with it ?

Comment: here's a example of unique modal with ID parameters -> [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4g0k-bbrp) (run F9 to see the effect). very basic/simple: in your case, the links would be generated in the query results loop. See if it would help, if so, I'll set up a quick fix to your code

Comment: thank's i've used the fonction and changed a little so i can recienve the var i needed thank's a lot !!!!

Comment: you're welcome, glad it help... you may want to update your question so it will hopefully help others later (see comments in answer), and close this one. happy coding ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As it helped you, I post the comments/example as an answer, and you may want to update your question, providing the future readers with the initial code updated with your solution, so it helps others.*

**You need to identify the div/modal with a ID that needs to be unique**, then, use jQuery to launch and grab the ID. Either you create one modal, then pass ID param on click, or keep it your way, but need unique ID as well.

here's a example of unique modal with ID parameters : very basic/simple. In your case, the links would be generated in the query results loop.

We'll use the [jQuery .attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) -> value of the attribute that was clicked, using `$(this)` to identify it.

> jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".modal-trigger").click(function(e){
  // on click, we grab ID of the link
  e.preventDefault();
  dataIDModal = $(this).attr("data-id"); // this is the unique ID needed
  // HTML links will have a 'data-id' containing what you need from PHP

  $("#modal").css({"display":"block"}); // display the modal
  $("#modal > .modal-box >.modal-body").load("modal-content.inc.php?id="+dataIDModal);
  // the line above is used to load php page in the modal body
  // PHP will extract data from DB with the selected ID using GET
 });

 $(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").click(function(){
 // click on 'close' or 'overlay' will close the modal
 $(".modal").css({"display":"none"});
 });

 });
```

> HTML

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
 <div class="modal-sandbox"></div>
  <div class="modal-box">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="close-modal">&#10006;</div> 
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
 </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the PHP loop, echo each link that will have unique ID from DB
(Note the 'data-id' used in jQuery part):

```
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-id="<?php echo"$my_unique_ID_from_DB"; ?>">Load Modal with ID <?php echo"$my_unique_ID_from_DB"; ?></a>
```

*CSS is not really mandatory, as anyone will have different needs, so it's not posted here*