# Show variable on a modal from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am trying to make a modal windows where you can see an URL. That URL is stored in a mysql database. I am generating a table with all the data from that table and some hyperlinks, one of then should be that modal window. By far I have this, but its only showing the empty modal window.

PHP main page:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' id='myBtn'>Url</a></td>";
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<?php
include('url.php');
?>
</div>
```

PHP modal page:

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Send to:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>URL</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var a = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

a.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I was wondering how can I make it, as I dont know how to pass data from my hyperlink to the modal or if I should make a modal for each id.

Comment: `if I should make a modal for each id` -> I'd rather suggest you create one modal, then pass ID param to `url.php` on click

Comment: That <div id="myModal2" was a mistake, it should be myModal only, edited it. My sql is like $row["url"] when I generate the table, but as I dont know hwo to pass the param to url.php its not in the code yet.

Comment: check if this can help -> [information into a popup box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200645/how-to-take-the-information-of-a-div-into-a-popup-box/44220292#44220292)